# How to print full page of SPA to pdf using NodeJS and Puppeteer correctly?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pdf-generation, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

Please help me to generate the pdf file from the page of react single-page application with client-side rendering.
I have implement the client app with button "Save as pdf" and server-side endpoint with puppeteer code (see below).
When I click "Save as pdf" I want to see the pdf file with full current page, but I see only first page with only visible content.
Where is error in my code?

Thanks in advance.

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3005;

const printPdf = async (projectId, reportName) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  page.setViewport({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080
  });

  page.goto(
    `http://localhost:3000/project/${projectId}/report/${reportName}`,
    { waitUntil: "networkidle2" }
  );

  await page.waitForNavigation();
  await page.type("#username", process.env.USERNAME);
  await page.type("#password", process.env.PASSWORD);
  await page.click("#submit");
  await page.waitForSelector(".content", { visible: true });

  const pdfFile = await page.pdf({
    format: "A4",
    printBackground: true
  });

  await browser.close();

  return pdfFile;
};

app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("combined"));

app.get("/export", function(req, res) {
  const { projectId, reportName } = req.query;

  printPdf(projectId, reportName)
    .then(pdf => {
      res.set({
        "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
        "Content-Length": pdf.length
      });

      res.send(pdf);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("!!ERROR", error);
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server running on port %d", PORT);
});
```

Comment: I've used React PDF (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf) to do this before. However it does involve some work to build the page again uing the react-pdf syntax. Would be difficult depending on the complexity of your page.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the settings below. I got the pdf without those lines. Seems to be an issue with the navigation. try increase the waiting timout instead.

```
//remove this    
 await page.waitForNavigation();
 await page.type("#username", process.env.USERNAME);
 await page.type("#password", process.env.PASSWORD);
 await page.click("#submit");
 await page.waitForSelector(".content", { visible: true });
```

These are the code i used and worked.

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3005;

const printPdf = async () => {
    console.log('i am in');
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    page.setViewport({
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080
    });

    await page.goto('https://news.ycombinator.com', {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
    });

    const pdfFile = await page.pdf({
        format: 'A4',
        printBackground: true
    });

    await browser.close();

    return pdfFile;
};

app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('combined'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    printPdf()
        .then(pdf => {
            res.set({
                'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
                'Content-Length': pdf.length
            });

            res.send(pdf);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('!!ERROR', error);
        });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Server running on port %d', PORT);
});
```

Comment: No, I need authorize before navigate to this service.

Comment: I cannot test it or debug it with authentication, i've used puppeteer with authentication with firebase. Can you provide us a stackblitz with a basic authetication to test it up?

Comment: I've found the problem.
See the next snippet (spoiler: height) :-)))

.content {
  /* height: calc(100vh - var(--header-height)); */
  height: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 8px 24px 8px 24px;
}